# Medical Ultrasonography Phased Array Beamforming

Tags: wave, ultrasound, transducer

Medical ultrasonography equipment images the interior of the body by reflecting ultrasonic sound waves off of discontinuities between internal tissues / organs. I did some reading about this technology and how it is possible to develop a two dimensional image from only the reflected sound. It seems that modern sonograms work by having phased arrays of both elements which transmit the sound waves and which receive the sound waves. The phased arrays of transmitters allow the energy to be focused in a particular direction, and the phased arrays of receivers allow the device to pick out reflections coming from that direction. I have two questions.

1. Is it necessary to have phased arrays of both transmitters and receivers, or is it simply more efficient that way? Could an instrument be constructed with a single receiver and a phased array of transmitters, or conversely a single transmitter and a phased array of receivers? Would it work, albeit with reduced noise rejection?
2. The phased arrays explain to me how the beam can be directed in a 2D plane, but how does this extend to three dimensions? How does the device reject reflections outside the plane it is imaging?

Answer (score 1):

ad1) While transmitting the signal could come back, therefore if the object is far ditant it could send a burst then switch to receive, but I think a more stable solution is to have a transmitting array and receiveing array separated.
ad2) It is possible to send a directed cone in spherical coordinate sytem, then to receive the reflected signal. The reflected signal indeed comes with a delay, therefore the possibility to differentiate the timestamp of sent signal is to encode the sent signal with some orthogonal function and then doing the correlation, in few words: you do encode xmit signal with a known function, then when you receive you do the correlation between recived and sent signal, so you get the exact delay (travell) time. Imaging usualy uses those chirp signals that can reject near objects (the transmitter itself) by use of correlation math.

Answer (score 0):

1. This depends somewhat on the technology used, but it's actually less complicated to develop a high-resolution 'model' from the reflections using an array of transmitter/receivers that each only receive their own reflections. Alternately, at the cost of a little more complexity in decoding, different transmitters could be pulsed seperately, taking a "picture" of the reflections from each, by all receivers independently, then overlaying the results (this allows you to "look around" some obstructions without moving your array).
2. Using different phasing, a collinear array can exercise primarily 1-dimensional control over output/input beamforming (google "side fire antenna array" and "end fire antenna array" to see examples of this phasing control), a 3+ element coplanar (but non-collinear) array can exercise 2-dimensional beam forming/steering, and 4+ element non coplanar arrays can theoretically form/steer their "beam" in any direction in a sphere, simply by phasing.